# send 50k post requests within a minute

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, http, concurrency

I want to load-test a system so I want to send around 50k POST requests within a minute. I want to do this for around 4 hours consecutively. The URL and payload is always the same. I just need to play around with the number of requests.

This is what I tried:

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures
import time
....
events_per_minute_target = 50000

# Calculate the total number of events to send
total_events = events_per_minute_target * 60 * 2 * 2  

# Set the duration for each minute
duration_per_minute = 60

start_time = time.time()

def send_request(_):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 2xx)
        if response.ok:
            print(f"Request successful. Response: {response.text}")
        else:
            print(f"Request failed. Status code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.text}")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Use a ThreadPoolExecutor to send requests concurrently for x minutes
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for _ in range(duration_per_minute * 2 * 2):  
        # Submit tasks to the executor
        futures = {executor.submit(send_request, None) for _ in range(events_per_minute_target)}

        # Wait for all tasks to complete
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

# Calculate the actual events per minute for the entire test duration
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
actual_events_per_minute = total_events / (elapsed_time / 60)

print(f"Load test completed. Actual events per minute: {actual_events_per_minute:.2f}")
```

But my Python script keeps running after 4 hours as well so I am not sure if this is behaving as intended or not. Since it's running after 2 hours as well, i get an impression that it failed to send 50k requests within a minute.

What could be an alternate approach?

Edit:

After running for more than 4 hours, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/snowplow/gtm_load_test/gtm.py", line 222, in <module>
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures, timeout=duration_per_minute * 4):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 239, in as_completed
    raise TimeoutError(
TimeoutError: 45835 (of 50000) futures unfinished
```

Comment: Is this internal/local requests? Or is this 50K different urls?

Comment: it's a simple post request. 50k requests to the same URL, with the same payload @Cow

Comment: Why `2 * 2`?  You have `total_events = events_per_minute_target * 60 * 2 * 2 ` is that not four hours worth of events not two?  Same with `range(duration_per_minute * 2 * 2)`

Comment: Point. But the problem is still the same, it runs longer than 4 hours and fails and eventually throws an error. See the edited qs @JonSG